# Cursor goes blank in the terminal and website not responding? Using NodeJs with Mysql and Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, node-modules

When i ran the code on the terminal " **node app.js** ", terminal answers back " ***Server running on 8080*** " and cursor goes blank after that. Then i open " ***localhost:8080*** " from the browser and it gives " ***we have 1500 users in our db" which is what is expected*** ".

But the issue is cursor at the terminal goes blank after giving " ***Server running on 8080*** ". How can i make that cursor doesn't go blank, rather it continues to work. Because when i open a new terminal, the code that i ran doesn't work.  I tried putting " ***connection.end();*** " at the end of the code but it is still not working.

When i run the code after opening a new terminal it gives this error on terminal:

<
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:215:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Connection.query (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
    at E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\app.js:15:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\Folders\Helloworld\Node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT',
  fatal: false
}

> Blockquote

MY CODE IS:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '********',
    database : '**********'
  });

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users";
connection.query(q, function(err, results){
          if(err) throw err;
          var count = results[0].count;
    res.send("we have " + count + "user in our db");
    }); 
});



app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server running on 8080!");
});
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

So opening a new terminal doesn't work etiher. What causes terminal to stop and how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

That is NORMAL behavior. Node is busy running your app, and ready to display any console.log() you perform.

Just open ANOTHER terminal session.

I personally rarely use the terminal within VSCode. I tend to tab to my other window with a git-bash prompt open.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can hit Ctrl + C together and it should open up a new command line for you, without having to close terminal altogether.